# Draw Database Schema based on JPA entities in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

Does anyone know if there is a plugin available for IntelliJ that will draw the database schema diagram based on JPA entity classes?

Answer (score 9):

IntelliJ (ultimate edition) can generate an ER diagram, without any additional plugins.
It's available from the context menu in the "Persistence" pane.

To get that pane, you'll need to add a "JPA" facet to your module first.

Comment: how do you add the JPA facet to your module?  I can't seem to find that.

Comment: In Project Structure (Ctrl-Shift-Alt-S), you'll see a list of modules. There's a "+" (plus) button above the module list. Clicking it will allow you to add various facets to existing modules.

Examples are: Spring, GWT, Hibernate and JPA.

Note that support for "enterprisey" frameworks (like JPA) is not part of the free IntelliJ "Community" edition.

Answer (score 7):

pre-requisite to get "ER Diagram" entry in the context menu :

- ultimate version (seems not be available into the "Community version")
- JPA Facet onto the module
- UML Plugin activated (files/other settings/configure plugins ; this plugin enables  diagrams)

  - then Right clic onto the "persistenceUnit" into the "Persistence" tool windows

I just add this comment into the official documentation (comment awaiting moderation).

Official doc : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/opening-jpa-or-hibernate-er-diagram.html

Answer (score 7):

File, Project Settings, click "+". Select the module which contains Java classes annotated with JPA.
Then add JPA facet like this:
[image]

Make sure you choose your framework correctly:

[image]

Then follow this steps:

[image]